# 同じ画面内で特定のエリアのみcssを反映させたい

Tags: css

以下HTMLで、titile_area,body_areaのみCSSを反映させたいが、どうしたらいいか？
現状は、titile_area,body_area以外の部分にも適用されてしまう。

```
<div class="title_area">
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>A</th>
    <th>B</th>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>

<div class="body_area">
  <table>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1a</td>
      <td>1b</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2a</td>
      <td>2b</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

<div class="x_area">
<!-- この内部では以下CSSを適用させたくない -->
<table>
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>A Xarea</th>
    <th>B Xarea</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>1a Xarea</td>
    <td>1b Xarea</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

<div>
<!-- ここには、id,classがない。この内部では以下CSSを適用させたくない -->
<table>
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>AAAA title</th>
    <th>BBBB title</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>1aaaaa</td>
    <td>1bbbbb</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

```css
div.body_area  thead, tbody {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
div.body_area tr {
    width: 100%;
}
div.body_area tbody {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
div.title_area tbody {
    width: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

質問文の CSS を読むと、すべての `table` 要素の子孫要素へ適用される装飾は、 `tbody` 要素に対する装飾のみであることがわかります。なぜなら、 `tbody` 要素以外の要素は以下のように、**クラス名によって適用される要素の親要素が限定されている**ためです。

- `.body_area` クラスが付与された `div` 要素の子孫にある `tbody`, `thead`, `tr` 要素

  ```css
  div.body_area thead {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
  }

  div.body_area tr {
    width: 100%;
  }

  div.body_area tbody {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
  }
  ```
- `.title_area` クラスが付与された `div` 要素の子孫にある `tbody` 要素

  ```css
  div.title_area tbody {
    width: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
  }
  ```

そのため、今回修正する必要があるセレクタは `tbody` 要素に対するものだけであるということになり、これは開発者ツールを使用することでも確認が出来ます。装飾を適用したい `tbody` 要素は、 HTML を読むと、 **`class` 属性が付与されており、かつ `.x_area` クラスが適用されていない `div` 要素の子孫に存在する `tbody` 要素**だとわかります。これをセレクタとして書き起こすと、 `div[class]:not(.x_area) tbody` というようになります。

```css
div.body_area thead,
tbody {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

div.body_area tr {
  width: 100%;
}

div.body_area tbody {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

div.title_area tbody {
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class="title_area">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>A</th>
      <th>B</th>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

<div class="body_area">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1a</td>
        <td>1b</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2a</td>
        <td>2b</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

<div class="x_area">
  <!-- この内部では以下CSSを適用させたくない -->
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>A Xarea</th>
        <th>B Xarea</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1a Xarea</td>
        <td>1b Xarea</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

<div>
  <!-- ここには、id,classがない。この内部では以下CSSを適用させたくない -->
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>AAAA title</th>
        <th>BBBB title</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1aaaaa</td>
        <td>1bbbbb</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

このセレクタを用いて CSS を以下のように編集します。すると、 `div` 要素のうち装飾を行わない要素のみ、ユーザーエージェントスタイルシート以外の装飾が行われていないことから、このセレクタが正しく動作し、質問者さんの実現したいことが行えたということがわかります。

```css
div.body_area thead,
div[class]:not(.x_area) tbody {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

div.body_area tr {
  width: 100%;
}

div.body_area tbody {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

div.title_area tbody {
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class="title_area">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>A</th>
      <th>B</th>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

<div class="body_area">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1a</td>
        <td>1b</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2a</td>
        <td>2b</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

<div class="x_area">
  <!-- この内部では以下CSSを適用させたくない -->
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>A Xarea</th>
        <th>B Xarea</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1a Xarea</td>
        <td>1b Xarea</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

<div>
  <!-- ここには、id,classがない。この内部では以下CSSを適用させたくない -->
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>AAAA title</th>
        <th>BBBB title</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1aaaaa</td>
        <td>1bbbbb</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```